# Converting SQL query result to Linq result with an new field that is not in the Model

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an SQL query,

```
SELECT 
    c.AssignedTo ,c.CampaignID, c.Name, c.Venue,c.StartedOn, 
    c.CompletedOn, c.IsOpen, COUNT(C.Name) AS Leads 
FROM 
    Campaign AS c 
RIGHT JOIN 
    Leads AS l ON l.CampaignID = c.CampaignID 
GROUP BY
    c.AssignedTo, c.CampaignID, c.Name,c.Venue,c.StartedOn, c.CompletedOn, c.IsOpen 
ORDER BY 
    c.AssignedTo
```

These are my two tables in that query, `CAMPAIGNS`:

```
[Table("Campaigns")]
public class Campaigns
{
    [Key]
    public int CampaignID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
        
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Venue { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsersReference")]
    public int AssignedTo { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompletedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }

    // To Reference Users table using FK
    public Users UsersReference { get; set; }
}
```

and `Leads`:

```
[Table("Leads")]
public class Leads
{
    [Key]
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
        
    [ForeignKey("CampaignsReference")]
    public int CampaignID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string ConsumerName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public string PreferredMoC { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateApproached { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductsReference")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    // To access Campaign and Product table through FK
    public Campaigns CampaignsReference { get; set; }
    public Products ProductsReference { get; set; }
}
```

My query returns a result likes this in SQL:

[image]

The `Leads` column is just the `COUNT()` of the columns matching with my `CampaignID`. I've used `context.Campaigns.FromSqlRaw()` but since my `Campaigns` doesn't have another column specifically for the count.

Is there a way to display my new field `Count()` using EF Core and Linq?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and adhere to naming conventions: singular names for classes (and plural for collections, if any). And no suffixes like `Reference`: i.e. `public Campaign Campaign { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ Query for such task.

```cs
var query =
    from l in ctx.Leads
    let c = l.CampaignsReference
    group c by new { c.AssignedTo, c.CampaignID, c.Name, c.Venue, c.StartedOn, c.CompletedOn, c.IsOpen } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.AssignedTo,
        g.Key.CampaignID, 
        g.Key.Name, 
        g.Key.Venue,
        g.Key.StartedOn, 
        g.Key.CompletedOn, 
        g.Key.IsOpen,
        Leads = g.Sum(x => x.Name != null ? 1 : 0)
    };

var query = query.OrderBy(x => x.AssignedTo);
```